# How to tell SSIS unpivot to make rows even when values is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, unpivot

I have this flat file that I import and it needs to be unpivoted. All works well except that I would like that the unpivot makes the rows even is the value is null.

I don't want to resort to some sort of hack to add -1 and replace the -1 after.

The software that uses the database expect to have always 3 rows for each line that was imported from the flat file even if it has null for value.

Some drawing to explain the problem

flat file line

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|id of person | code1 | value1 | code2 | value2 | code3 | value3|
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
|123          | hh1   | hh2    |  2    | hh3    |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
What I get is

------------------------------
|id of person | code | value | 
------------------------------
|123          |  hh2 |  2    |
------------------------------
what I want


------------------------------
|id of person | code | value | 
------------------------------
|123          |hh1   | null  |
------------------------------
|123          |hh2   |   2   |
------------------------------
|123          |hh3   | null  |
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the table you meant to have to get the result you want.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|id of person | code1 | value1 | code2 | value2 | code3 | value3|
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
|123          | hh1   | NULL   |  hh2  |   2    |  hh3  |  NULL |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not positive if you can do this with the **Unpivot** Data Flow Transformation, however you can easily accomplish this in a script task with an asynchronous output.  To use an asynchronous output you have to make a change to the Output properties of the transformation script task under **Inputs and Outputs**.  Set **SynchronousInputID** to **None**

After that the following code should work for you.

```
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID;
        Output0Buffer.Code = Row.Code1;
        Output0Buffer.Value = Row.Value1;

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID;
        Output0Buffer.Code = Row.Code2;
        Output0Buffer.Value = Row.Value2;

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID;
        Output0Buffer.Code = Row.Code3;
        Output0Buffer.Value = Row.Value3;
    }
```

This will create 3 new rows for every 1 row.  I assumed that your identifier is **ID**.